# QuickBook API integration ,Issue Adding Bill Payment at US company

Tags: asp.net, quickbooks

I am trying to add the **Bill payment** from my application ,Validation error Coming :
Required param **CheckPayment/CreditCardPayment** is missing in the request .

Unable to Get the Soluction .Ref Image [image]

Entire Connectivity is going well But Issue of Missing Parameter is coming .
I just CODE the Following :

```
protected void btnBillPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var dataService = GetDataService();
                var context = GetServiceContext();

                decimal _amount = 200m;

                BillPayment billPayment = new BillPayment
                {
                    VendorRef = new ReferenceType
                    {
                        Value = "71",
                        name = "Lotus"
                    },
                    APAccountRef = new ReferenceType
                    {
                        name = "Fuel",
                        Value = "56"
                    },
                    PayType = BillPaymentTypeEnum.Check,
                    PayTypeSpecified = true,
                    BillPaymentEx = new IntuitAnyType
                    {
                    },
                    TotalAmt = _amount,
                    TotalAmtSpecified = true,
                    domain = "QBO",
                    MetaData = new ModificationMetaData
                    {
                        CreateTime = DateTime.Now,
                        LastUpdatedTime = DateTime.Now
                    },
                    TxnDate = DateTime.Now,
                    TxnDateSpecified = true,
                    //DepartmentRef=new ReferenceType
                    //{

                    //},
                    CurrencyRef = new ReferenceType()
                                {
                                    //name = ?,
                                    //Value = ?
                                },
                    PrivateNote = "Private Note",
                    Line = new Line[] 
                    {
                        new Line
                        {
                            Amount=_amount,
                            AmountSpecified=true,

                            LinkedTxn=new LinkedTxn[]
                            {
                                new LinkedTxn
                                {
                                    TxnId="234",
                                    TxnType="Bill"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },


                };
                BillPayment resultBillPayment = dataService.Add<BillPayment>(billPayment);
            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
                throw ex1;
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance for right guidance

Comment: I finally found it's not CheckPayment but BillPaymentCheck attribute ,I was Missing .

Answer (score 1):

You need a child object `CheckPayment` in your object to provide the payment details specific to Check Payments.

In other words, you told QuickBooks this was paid by check:

```
PayType = BillPaymentTypeEnum.Check,
```

But you didn't tell it details of this Check payment:

```
  "PayType": "Check",
  "CheckPayment": {
    "BankAccountRef": {
      "value": "35",
      "name": "Checking"
    }
  },
```

If you refer to Intuit's docs you'll see this indicated in their example:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/billpayment

And documented:

```
CheckPayment:
required if PayType is Check
BillPaymentCheck 
Reference to the vendor for this transaction.

CreditCardPayment:
required if PayType is CreditCard
BillPaymentCreditCard, filterable via CCAccountRef, sortable 
Information about a credit card payment for the transaction. Not applicable to Estimate and SalesOrder. Used when PayType is CreditCard.
```

Together with the child attributes indicated too:

```
BillPaymentCheck 
Reference to the vendor for this transaction.

Child attributes

BankAccountRef:
required
ReferenceType, filterable, sortable 
Reference to the bank account. Query the Account name list resource to determine the appropriate Account object to reference here. Use Account.Id and Account.Name from that object for APAccountRef.value and APAccountRef.name, respectively. The specified account must have Account.AccountType set to Bank and Account.AccountSubType set to Checking.

PrintStatus:
optional
PrintStatusEnum, default is NeedToPrint 
Printing status of the invoice. 
Valid values: NotSet, NeedToPrint, PrintComplete.
```

Comment: I already tried same but CheckPayment element is not available .I already gone through those documentation.

Comment: Now after struggling a lot i got ,i found it is not CheckPayment but BillPaymentCheck attribute .which is the required parameter .

Really QuickBooks have documented the API Badly.. :(